# How to correctly draw a circle with gaps in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

I want to draw a circle. But, not really. I want a series of arcs (segments) that will imply a full circle. And it'll spin and it will be awesome. But I am obviously doing something wrong.
[Please, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utWdM/](http://jsfiddle.net/utWdM/)

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(111, 56%, 50%, 0.67)';
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, Math.PI * 8 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 12 / 30, Math.PI * 20 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 24 / 30, Math.PI * 32 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 36 / 30, Math.PI * 44 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 48 / 30, Math.PI * 56 / 30);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

draw();
```

I don't want the line from the center to the start of an arc (and the first one doesn't have it).
I've been studying basic drawing with canvas and hope understand what's going on and more someday, but I couldn't wait to know what's wrong in this situation.
Any help, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moveTo needs to be to the beginning of the arc not the centre. This is most easily achieved by translating to the centre of the circle as below. http://jsfiddle.net/utWdM/1

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(111, 56%, 50%, 0.67)';
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.translate(250,250);
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI * 8 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(100*Math.cos(Math.PI*12/30), 100*Math.sin(Math.PI*12/30));
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, Math.PI * 12 / 30, Math.PI * 20 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(100*Math.cos(Math.PI*24/30), 100*Math.sin(Math.PI*24/30));
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, Math.PI * 24 / 30, Math.PI * 32 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(100*Math.cos(Math.PI*36/30), 100*Math.sin(Math.PI*36/30));
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, Math.PI * 36 / 30, Math.PI * 44 / 30);
        ctx.moveTo(100*Math.cos(Math.PI*48/30), 100*Math.sin(Math.PI*48/30));
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, Math.PI * 48 / 30, Math.PI * 56 / 30);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Note: Since you're translating in draw() you might want to wrap with ctx.save/ctx.restore.  Otherwise any further calls to draw() will accumulate translations and drive the drawing off the canvas.  An addition towards what the questioner is needing: Since you're already translating to the centerpoint, you might as well add ctx.rotate(radianAngle) which will make your arc-circle rotatable as well.

Comment: Great! It works, as the fiddle shows, and it helped me refresh my knowledge of cosine, sine and the unit circle. That helps right now and will be useful in the long run. So, thank you very much!

Comment: The understanding of where I should be "moving to" and how to calculate it is exactly what I needed. I think I was mostly geometrically lost. =P For now, the "final" product can be seen here in its full glory!: http://anzol.biz/

Answer (score 3):

If you want a little flexible solution, ie. if you want to change number of segments, size of each segments, then you can create a generic function such as this:

```
/**
 * ctx      = context
 * x / y    = center
 * radius   = of circle
 * offset   = rotation in angle (radians)
 * segments = How many segments circle should be in
 * size     = size of each segment (of one segment) [0.0, 1.0]
*/
function dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, offset, segments, size) {

    var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI,             /// cache 2*Math.PI = 360 degrees in rads
        segs = pi2 / segments,         /// calc. size of each segment in rads
        len = segs * size,             /// calc. length of segment in rads
        i = 0,
        ax, ay;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(offset);                /// rotate canvas
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);

    for(; i < pi2; i += segs) {
        ax = x + radius * Math.cos(i); /// calculate start position of arc
        ay = y + radius * Math.sin(i);
        ctx.moveTo(ax, ay);            /// make sure to move to beginning of arc
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, i, i + len); /// draw arc
    }

    ctx.restore();                     /// remove rotation
}
```

Then in you code you simply call:

```
ctx.beginPath();

dashedCircle(ctx, 250, 250, 100, 0, 5, 0.7);

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(111, 56%, 50%, 0.67)';
ctx.stroke();
/// don't closePath here
```

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/utWdM/10/)**

Using the offset parameter makes it a breeze to rotate it:

```
var offset = 0;
var step = 0.03;
var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;

(function loop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();

    dashedCircle(ctx, 250, 250, 100, offset % pi2, 5, 0.7);
    ctx.stroke();

    offset += step;

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

**[Rotating circle fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/utWdM/11/)**

Comment: Wow! Awesome! I'm studying your fiddles to understand them as well as possible. And I already learned a lot! At first, size wasn't clear at all. Now I see it is like a relative size. How much of the arc shall really be drawn. Considering that each arc is a piece of the full circle. It is really smart and it's the kind of insight I would like to internalize.

Comment: Right now my needs were very specific but still, what I learned with your code is invaluable. Thank you very much. =D
My objective for now has already been acomplished!: http://anzol.biz/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid complicated math is to call `.beginPath()` and `.stroke();` for each segment. I know it's very repetitive but that how it would look like:

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(111, 56%, 50%, 0.67)';

        ctx.beginPath();        
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, Math.PI * 8 / 30);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 12 / 30, Math.PI * 20 / 30);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 24 / 30, Math.PI * 32 / 30);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 36 / 30, Math.PI * 44 / 30);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, Math.PI * 48 / 30, Math.PI * 56 / 30);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

draw();
```

And here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utWdM/13/

Comment: At first, I tried something like this. It works indeed, but I felt like I was missing something important. Eventually, I realized that the complicated math wasn't that complicated and actually very fun. =D A knowledge I'll use again and again in the future.

Comment: There is something else. I came to understand that `closePath` isn't necessary here. It is not `endPath`. It doesn't do what I imagine it did. A valuable lesson. You can see it for yourself in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utWdM/7/.

Comment: closePath() connects end point with start point and is not needed for an arc. Besides, there is no point calling it *after* the stroke() as stroke is the method rasterizing the (outline of the) path.

Comment: @jaywalking101 Cool! Glad I could learn something from it too. I updated my answer.